# Is this BA15X flight a logistic flight for British Airways?

Tags: flight-planning, boeing-777, australia

Right now (26/11/2015, UTC 17:16), British Airways is flying over the Australian Outback with two Boeing 777-336(ER)s, christened flight **BA15** (http://www.flightradar24.com/BAW15/8169bb5) and **BA15X**, which is slightly ahead (http://www.flightradar24.com/BAW15X/8169237).

Why is this? Is flight **BA15X** a logistic one? And if not, why did they use an "X" to distinguish between the two instead of another number?

**EDIT**

I am also wondering: is this going to cost extra money to `BA`, owing to the new slot they had to purchase or rent for operating a contemporary, second aircraft at `SYD`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The Wednesday flight was indeed delayed for a full day as was suggested in a comment.

[image]

Comment: Is this going to cost extra money to `BA`, owing to the new slot they had to purchase or rent for operating a contemporary, second aircraft at `SYD`?

Comment: It will cost extra money for the changed/additional slot at Heathrow, for sure. There may be costs at other airports. As to the aircraft, it depends whether BA had another suitable, unutilised aircraft available (this is a fairly quiet time of year, so it's not unreasonable to guess that BA may have had a spare at Heathrow...). But yes, this will (overall) have cost BA some money: any significant delay does